# Why is my changes ignored to releaseupdate scripts in dynamics ax 2012 r2

Tags: x++, dynamics-ax-2012

I have a problem with the ReleaseUpdateDB60_Basic.updateAdjustment_RU script -> UPDATE RASSETADJUSTMENTTABLE SET  = LTRIM(), is a syntax error. If i comment the line that generates this sql out, sync, recompile, then the error still persist when I run the script.

We are upgrading from AX 2009 to AX 2012 R2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remember to do the incremental CIL update. Upgrade scripts are run in batch, which uses the CIL.